# EOF on macos and centos different result

Tags: c, macos, centos

I'm using EOF to jump out of a 'while' loop, and want to input some numbers by 'scanf'.The 'scanf' outside the loop doesn't work on macos.

I've tried running this code on macos and centos.The result on centos is what I need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
 int i;
 //ctrl+d=EOF
 while(scanf("%d",&i) != EOF){
  printf("?");
 }
 printf("\nloopend\n");
 //those 'scanf' are ignored on macos.
 scanf("%d",&i);
 scanf(" %d",&i);
 scanf("%d ",&i);
 printf("\nend\n");
}
```

Input(without ','):
1,\n,ctrl+d

Output(centos):

```
1
?
loopend
//waiting for input here
```

Output(macos):

```
1
?
loopend

end
//the program ended directly
```

Comment: Why `scanf("%d",&i) != EOF` instead of `scanf("%d",&i) == 1`?

Comment: Try calling `clearerr(stdin);` after the loop

Comment: Please don't test `scanf`'s return value for `EOF`.  Please *do* test `scanf`'s return value for the number of items you expected to scan.

Comment: @M.M  Thanks! `clearerr(stdin)` is exactly what I need.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thank you! Actually I expect a sign which is not a normal number to end the loop.

Comment: @chux Then I can only type '1' to keep this loop. It's not what I need. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MacOS behaviour is correct. According to the [C standard §7.21.7.1/3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.1p3) (the `fgetc` library function),  the end-of-file indication is sticky; once `fgetc` sees an EOF, it must set the file's end-of-file indicator which will cause subsequent calls to return `EOF` until the end-of-file indicator is cleared, for example with `clearerr()`:

> If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end- of-file indicator for the stream is set and the fgetc function returns EOF. Otherwise, the fgetc function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by stream. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and the fgetc function returns EOF.

Since other input functions, including `scanf`, are supposed to act as if implemented by repeated calls to `fgetc`, EOF should be sticky for them, too. If you want to continue reading after you receive an EOF return, you should call `clearerr()` on the stream. (Or something else which resets the indicator, such as `seek()`.)

For many years, the Gnu implementation of the standard C library did not follow the standard. It only reported EOF once, leaving the next `fgetc` to wait for more input on devices like terminals and pipes. The bug, reported in 2006, was [finally fixed in v2.28](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;h=2cc7bad0ae0a412e75270be5ed41d45c03e7a931), released in August 2018, although that might not yet be part of the Centos distro.

[*Note: there is a longer discussion about this behaviour in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32323262/1566221), including a now-outdated grump (by me) and some links to historic discussions about the issue.*]

In any case, it has always been clear that portable code should call `clearerr()`, since BSD-derived standard library implementations (including MacOS) follow the standard as quoted above.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree that the GNU library is aberrant — it shouldn't matter that it's a terminal input (which is required to get that behaviour).  Once EOF is seen, it should remain 'seen' until and unless a `clearerr()` call is made.

Comment: @jonathan. Yeah, I've been complaining about this for years. But apparently glibc was finally fixed, so I edited the answer.

Comment: If it has been fixed at last, then "was aberrant" is more appropriate than "is aberrant".  Version 2.28 was released in August 2018; current version is 2.29 (2019-01-31).  New versions are released every 6 months.  Not quite a year since the fix release — it will only be available in leading edge systems (not the stuff I work with, regrettably).  (See https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2018-08/msg00003.html in the section "Deprecated and removed features, and other changes affecting compatibility".)

Comment: @jonathan: exactly the message I found when searching for the thread in which glibc maintainers obstinately insisted that the behaviour wouldn't be changed. Nice surprise, although it's no longer really relevant to anything I do.

Comment: I wonder if they can get `pwrite()` fixed so that it isn't broken (according to the POSIX spec) by `O_APPEND` mode?  Probably not; that's more likely to be a bug in the kernel than the GNU C Library.

Comment: @jonathanleffler yup documented kernel feature, as I read so on the manages just this week...

Comment: I'm glad to read your paragraph starting "For many years,"  , that behaviour always puzzled me by contradicting how I thought streams were supposed to work (i.e. if it's closed it's closed)

Comment: "once fgetc sees an EOF, it must set the file's end-of-file indicator which will cause subsequent calls to return EOF " --> as I read the spec, an `EOF` returned due to a rare input error is not sticky - even thought the end-of-file flag is sticky.  An EOF due to input error may or may not be followed by a non-`EOF` result.

Comment: @chux: you're probably right. But that's not an EOF; it's an fgetc call which returns EOF. I didn't say that EOF was sticky once fgetc returns an EOF; I said it was sticky once it *sees* an EOF. If there's an error, the error flag is set but apparently it's not required that `fgetc` test the error flag.