# Does fgetc return EOF on every call after end-of-file reached?

Tags: c, libc

Given the following C code:

```
int eofCount = 0;
while (true) {
    int c = fgetc(stdin); 
    if (c == EOF) eofCount++;
}
```

Will eofCount ever become greater than 1?

I can't find anything in C docs describing what happens with fgetc after EOF has been reached once. I know I can do this book-keeping myself, but if the stdlib does it for me that'd be great.

I'm not looking for code snippets because I've already try this with glibc and in fact eofCount is incremented past EOF. I would like stdlib source code reference or spec that confirms this is the defined behavior. Relying on undefined behavior could lead to problems down the road.

Comment: It probably does, but it might not be safe to assume. Can you say more about what you're really trying to do?

Comment: Some basic stream processing. I have my own lib that takes file pointers and does some basic stuff, and I was wondering if the caller of this lib needs to take care to not call it with EOF'd files. I agree that it looks like undefined behavior but I was wondering if someone knows better.

Comment: @Alexandre My answer is downvoted three times but I think that you will find it useful. You will have to click to see it.

Comment: Thank you for improving your answer. I have upvoted it. What I'm really looking for is a reference that confirms this, otherwise we might just be using undefined behavior which could cause problems down the line.

Comment: What use does this have?

Comment: The code itself is useless. It's simply to illustrate the question. The use in the question is not having to track EOF file state.

Comment: @Alexandre compilers overrule the specifications. :)

Comment: You seem not to have searched or read very well. The standard and the POSIX man-page are very clear about the behaviour.

Comment: @user902384: Only for implementation-defined and undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Olaf True words.

Comment: [Glibc bug 1190](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1190) The bug was filed in 2005, although the behaviour is much older than that. Not really a duplicate question but highly relevant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889296/how-to-end-scanf-by-entering-only-one-eof/19890073#19890073 And my take on the issue from another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322792/why-multiple-eof-enters-to-end-program/32323262#32323262

Comment: @Olaf there are times when specification clash and then compiler docs come in picture. Programs run not specifications.

Comment: @user902384: In this case, it is not the compiler but the particular implementation of the standard C library, which is *not* the same thing.

Comment: @user902384: There is no "clashing" about behaviour defined by the standard. A compiler not following the standard is not a compliant implementation, thus not a C compiler wrt the standard. Of couse the name "C" is not copyrighted, so there is no legal penalty for calling it "C compiler". Nevertheless it must not call itself "standard compliant". Similar for the **standard C library** implementation. And that's what we are talking about.

Comment: @Olaf I am talking about different standards clashing in much broader sense. Not one.

Comment: @user902384: Which different standards do you think are involved here?? There is only **one** C standard. And that is very clear about the behaviour. Did you even read it?

Comment: @Olaf I am sorry that I have gone out of scope of the question. There are quite a few C standards. C89, C99 and C11. Which one you are talking about? GCC has not even implemented threads because of glibc issue. I am referring to https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status

Comment: @user902384: As far as I know, this was always the standardized behaviour of `fgetc`. But it has never been the actual behaviour of glibc when the stream is a terminal.

Comment: @user902384: C90, 95 and 99 are **not** standard. They have been canceled (read the forewords!) with the release of their successor. Current C standard is ISO9899:2011. And how is that related to threads? If you refer to C11: C11-threads are **optional**.

Comment: @rici No more arguments. I have managed myself to get a ban from stackoverflow from asking questions. Now I do not want to lose the privilege of answering and commenting as well.

Comment: @Olaf last reply on this. Read the status page. Many are not even optional. Please.

Comment: @Olaf I am violating my words again. You definitely know the fate of `export` keyword in C++. No compiler with the exception of EDG ever implemented that.

Comment: @user902384: I have no idea what you are talking about. 1) C++ is a different, unrelated language. 2) THis is not the place for discussion, less about unrelated subjects.

Comment: @Olaf yes, you are right. I always forget the objective nature of stackoverflow and end up getting downvotes and bans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you're not reading from an interactive Linux terminal (i.e. you do not open a file or pipe stdin from some other file/process), once you read EOF all future reads will also read EOF.

If you are reading from a Linux terminal, pressing the key sequence for EOF (CTRL-D on Linux) will read as EOF but you can still enter in more characters and read them.

From section 7.21.7.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *3* If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is
>   set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`. Otherwise, the `fgetc`
>   function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to
>   by stream.  If  a  read  error  occurs,  the  error  indicator  for 
>   the  stream  is  set  and  the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`.

Comment: That's what I imagined but can we find a reference? I'm looking at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/glibc/+/cvs/libc-970216/stdio/fgetc.c and  https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/glibc/+/cvs/libc-970216/stdio/stdio.h to see if this is well defined in glibc.

Comment: That is confirmed as my programs gives count as one with following input sequence EOF 1 EOF.

Comment: @Alexandre: the C standard *is* a reference :) Another one is in Posix. However, glibc does not properly implement these references for non-file streams.

Comment: @dbush: Where in that excerpt from the C standard is the exception for terminals? :)

Comment: If Linux (actually most likely glibc) behaves like this it is not compliant.

Comment: @rici: POSIX just refers to the C standard for this behaviour.

Comment: @olaf: I know. But it can be referred to, so it's a reference. Personally I find this glibc bug really annoying but the odds of it being fixed in my lifetime seem very small.

Comment: @rici: I meant that POSIX just references the C standard, thus it is just another indirection. AFIK POSIX must not tell different than the C standard in general.

Comment: I'm with @Olaf. On a Mac, the EOF indicator gets set, and stays set, unless you use `clearerr(stdin)` to re-enable input. The behaviour described in this answer flies in the face of the C standard — it is not conformant. The quote supports this: _If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, …, the `fgetc` function returns EOF._ The only documented way to get the end-of-file indicator unset is via `clearerr()`. I wrote a program and ran it on my Mac and in an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM; it behaves completely differently in the two environments.  The Mac behaviour is the traditional behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

> Does fgetc return EOF on every call after end-of-file reached?

It depends of 2 *indicators* and I/O function calls.

---

Although not mentioned by OP, there are 2 reasons why `fgetc(stdin);` returns `EOF` and how they affect following `fgetc()` calls is not symmetric.  Further, use of various I/O functions affect 2 *indicators* that in turn affect following `fgetc()` calls

End-of-file.
Input error.

---

The C spec is explicit on the *end-of-ﬁle indicator* causing subsequent `EOF`.

> If the end-of-ﬁle indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a next character is present, the fgetc function obtains that character ... C11 §7.21.7.1 2

When end-of-file occurs or had occurred, a persistent flag is set: *end-of-ﬁle indicator*, so subsequent calls to `fgetc()` will return `EOF`.

> If the end-of-ﬁle indicator for the stream is set, **or** if the stream is at end-of-ﬁle, the end-of-ﬁle indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns`EOF` ... §7.21.7.1 3

---

When a rare input error occurs, `fgetc()` returns `EOF`, but that event does not set the *end-of-ﬁle indicator*, but an *error indicator* is set.  Subsequent calls do not necessarily return `EOF`, even though a *error indicator* is set.  IMO, the C spec is insufficiency clear on this point.

> If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF` §7.21.7.1 3

---

A call to `feof()`, and `ferror()` can be used to distinguish what caused the `EOF`, yet also may reflect prior I/O activity.  Thus good code promptly checks these functions after an `EOF` is returned and clears them if following I/O is to occur.

---

The *end-of-ﬁle indicator* and *error indicator* can be cleared with `void clearerr(FILE *stream);`

The `rewind()` function clears the  *error indicator*.

`ungetc()` will clear the *end-of-ﬁle indicator*.

Other I/O functions also affect these indicators.

---

Subsequent calls to `fgetc()` might not return `EOF` if the condition the caused the first `EOF` is removed and corresponding indicator is cleared.

Comment: I don't think the standard is unclear about an error condition. If the read error is encountered, the error flag is set. But a subsequent call might have no error, so it returns the next character. Said that, it is good practice to check for error after `fgetc(...) == EOF`. `feof` should be treated carefully; it's design is … problematic.

Answer (score -2):

Yes the count will become greater than one because you have an infinite `while` loop. You would find http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ useful.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    int eofCount = 0;
    /*while (true) {*/

    int c = fgetc(stdin); 
    if (c == EOF) eofCount++;
        c = fgetc(stdin); 
    if (c == EOF) eofCount++;
        c = fgetc(stdin); 
    if (c == EOF) eofCount++;

    /*}*/

printf("%d\n", eofCount);
return 0;
```

}

Compile and run. Hit ctrl+D twice on Linux and then enter. You will get 2.

This was compiled with `gcc -ansi -Wall -Werror -pedantic test.c` so it satisfied ANSI i.e. C89 standard.

Comment: That's not answering the question regarding EOF. The infinete loop is irrelevant if the `if` condition does not evaluate to true each time - which is what the question is really asking.

Comment: `Will eofCount ever become greater than 1?` this is _the_ question with "?"

Comment: Read the whole question. Context matters.

Comment: @kaylum Sorry for being hasty. I have updated the answer.